# Mongo GridFS find with projection issue

Tags: python, mongodb, projection, gridfs

I'm trying to do a query with projection in a GridFS like this:

```
Files = gridfs.GridFS(db)
f = Files.find({'metadata.AgentId': '1234'}, {'_id':1})
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: skip must be an instance of int
```

So, the initializer for Cursor is taking {'_id':1} as the third parameter >> skip.

On the other hand, this query is working fine in the Robo3T shell:

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `projection` parameter in `Gridfs.find` method.

https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/gridfs/index.html#gridfs.GridFS.find
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/gridfs/grid_file.py#L796-L802

Maybe you should use the collection's find.
https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find

```
db['fs.files'].find({'metadata.AgentId': '1234'}, {'_id':1})
```